# Can we number tag items on a window like in speech recognition

Tags: vbscript

I'm using a voice command software and its still in its beta but really good The only thing that I find a big problem is navigation in folders and files

In windows speech recognition software we can number tag the items on the window so we can select one

Is there a vb scripting way to do this.
eg; I give a command and it runs the vbs file which gives numbers to the clickable items on screen. I tell which number then vbs script shows a confirmation box and i give an ok the item is clicked

Is there a way to code this??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not easily with anything, not at all with vbscript. If you want to know more search on *UI Automation* - it's the accessability API. Note there are security hurdles with this so programs can't use UI Automation to steal info from other programs.